# datagrid is larger than usercontrol

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

My Mainpage has a menu that loads usercontrols into a Stackpannel.
I've got several usercontrols and some of them have a datagrid.
But when I bind a large collection to the datagrid, the datagrid gets much larger than the usercontrol. How can I set the max width/height of the grid to the size of the usercontrol.
It seems that the usercontrol's size also gets very large because of the size of the grids.

The mainpage had a Grid control:

The usercontrols are added to the ContainerSP

thanks!

Filip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackPanel assumes unlimited canvas, if you really want to control dynamic sizing, use a grid instead

Comment: It doesn't work, I replaced the stackpanels by grids, but the DataGrid in the UserControl is still larger than the window

Comment: Did you specify 1* as the grid's columns width (not auto)?